# Applying Picard–Lindelöf theorem for a second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

I'm trying to find the solution to the following IVP and prove its uniqueness by applying the Picard–Lindelöf theorem.

$$
y''+x^2y'+xy=0,\\ 
y(0)=y'(0)=0
$$

I've used the theorem in a few problems I've solved but the second order here confuses me. I know two things:

1. To apply the theorem , my equation has to be of the following form : $g'(x)=f(x,g)$
2. By setting $y'(x)=g(x)$ I can turn this into a first order system :
   $$y'(x)=g(x)\\g'(x)+x^2g(x)+xy=0$$

Now I can write the new equation like this:

$$g'(x)=-x^2g(x)-xy\ \implies g'(x)=f(x,g,y)$$

Because of the '$y$' term , this is not the form I'm looking for. Or is it? I know that $y$ is a function of $x$, so is it correct to write the following?
$$g'(x)=f(x,g,y(x))=f(x,g)$$

Normally I would go on and prove that f is continuous and Lipschitz in $x,g$. What do I do in this case ? Do I have to show that f is continuous and Lipschitz in $y$ as well?

Comment: I think the theorem is about *existence* of solutions and not how to get them, right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be like this
\begin{align}
y'(x)&=g(x)\\
g'(x)&=-x^2g(x)-xy(x)
\end{align}
With $v(x) = (y(x),g(x))^T$ as vector in $\mathbb R^2$ we get
$$
v'(x) = f(x,v(x)) = f(x,g(x),y(x)) = A(x)v(x)
$$
where $A(x)$ is the matrix
$$
A(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-x & -x^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The function $f(x,v(x))$ is Lipshitz in the second argument.